# How close and open same browser session firefox or chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions

I am trying to close and open same session in my browser with an extension of firefox then i have this code that close the browser and then open the last session, but the problem it is that open another window too. I need only open the last session whitout the other window.

My code in JS:

```
function close(){
   var gettingAll = browser.windows.getAll({ 
      populate: true, 
      windowTypes: ["normal"] 
  }); 

gettingAll.then((windows) => { 
     for (var item of windows) { 
     browser.windows.remove(item.id); 
   } 
 }); 
}

function restartSession {
   close(); 
   browser.windows.create().then(function (currentWindow) {
       browser.sessions.restore(); 
    }); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Browsers will naturally open a new tab once their are up.

This cannot be avoided, but you could write a js code to close the blank tab once the document is ready.

So basically the tab would open but close right away, within a second.

Comment: Not open a new tab, open a new window, the problem i think is with this code browser.windows.create,this create a window and then execute restore.sessions that restore the last session, the problem is that i cant do that restore.session work without windows.create that open another window

Comment: i need to restore session but in same window and i dont know how to do this